# Mac OS X Create User Script for 10.9 to 10.11

Tags: macos, shell, dscl

I would like to make a script, which checks the OS X Version and depending on that sysadminctl or dscl are invoked. As you can see, the script is checking the OS Version and checking the next available UserID. After that, the script jumps to the end and gives error of unexpected end of file.
What is missing here?

Thanks for your help!

```
#!/bin/sh

#  create_user_1.2.sh
#  
#
#

if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
echo "Sorry, you are not root."
exit 1
fi


# === For creating a User we need some input! ===

echo "Enter your desired user name: "
read USERNAME

echo "Enter a full name for this user: "
read FULLNAME

echo "Enter a password for this user: "
read -s PASSWORD

# ====


# A list of (secondary) groups the user should belong to
# This makes the difference between admin and non-admin users.

echo "Is this an administrative user? (y/n)"
read GROUP_ADD

if [ "$GROUP_ADD" = n ] ; then
    SECONDARY_GROUPS="staff"  # for a non-admin user
elif [ "$GROUP_ADD" = y ] ; then
    SECONDARY_GROUPS="admin _lpadmin _appserveradm _appserverusr" # for an admin user
else
    echo "You did not make a valid selection!"
fi

# ====

# check the OS X Version
OSXVERSION=$(sw_vers -productVersion | awk -F '.' '{print $1 "." $2}')

# Create a UID that is not currently in use
echo "Creating an unused UID for new user..."

# Find out the next available user ID
MAXID=$(dscl . -list /Users UniqueID | awk '{print $2}' | sort -ug | tail -1)
USERID=$((MAXID+1))

#if osx 10.10 then run
if [[ "$OSXVERSION" == "10.11" ]]; then
sysadminctl -addUser $USERNAME -fullName "$FULLNAME" -UID=$USERID -password $PASSWORD

else


#if osx 10.10 then run
if [[ "$OSXVERSION" == "10.10" ]]; then
sysadminctl -addUser $USERNAME -fullName "$FULLNAME" -UID=$USERID -password $PASSWORD

else

#if osx 10.9 then run
if [[ "$OSXVERSION" == "10.9" ]]; then

# Create the user account by running dscl (normally you would have to do each of these commands one
# by one in an obnoxious and time consuming way.
echo "Creating necessary files..."

dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME UserShell /bin/bash
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME RealName "$FULLNAME"
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME UniqueID "$USERID"
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME PrimaryGroupID 20
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME NFSHomeDirectory /Users/$USERNAME
dscl . -passwd /Users/$USERNAME $PASSWORD

# Create the home directory
echo "Creating home directory..."
createhomedir -c 2>&1 | grep -v "shell-init"

fi

# Add user to any specified groups
echo "Adding user to specified groups..."

for GROUP in $SECONDARY_GROUPS ; do
dseditgroup -o edit -t user -a $USERNAME $GROUP
done

echo "Created user #$USERID: $USERNAME ($FULLNAME)"

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple: The 'if' 'else' needs to be in the right order with 'elsif':

```
#if osx 10.10 then run
if [[ "$OSXVERSION" == "10.11" ]]; then
    echo "OS is 10.11"
sysadminctl -addUser $USERNAME -fullName "$FULLNAME" -UID=$USERID -password $PASSWORD

#if osx 10.10 then run

elif [[ "$OSXVERSION" == "10.10" ]]; then
    echo "OS is 10.10"
sysadminctl -addUser $USERNAME -fullName "$FULLNAME" -UID=$USERID -password $PASSWORD

#if osx 10.9 then run

elif [[ "$OSXVERSION" == "10.9" ]]; then

# Create the user account by running dscl
echo "Creating necessary files..."

dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME UserShell /bin/bash
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME RealName "$FULLNAME"
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME UniqueID "$USERID"
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME PrimaryGroupID 20
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME NFSHomeDirectory /Users/$USERNAME
dscl . -passwd /Users/$USERNAME $PASSWORD

# Create the home directory
echo "Creating home directory..."
createhomedir -c 2>&1 | grep -v "shell-init"

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are here and your system is running anything from 10.10 and newer, the sysadminctl command is your best friend. It does a lot of magic that DSCL can't do.

Here's the output for sysadminctl:

```
sysadminctl[21233:29122637] Usage: sysadminctl
    -deleteUser <user name> [-secure || -keepHome]
    -newPassword <new password> -oldPassword <old password> [-passwordHint <password hint>]
    -resetPasswordFor <local user name> -newPassword <new password> [-passwordHint <password hint>]
    -addUser <user name> [-fullName <full name>] [-UID <user ID>] [-password <user password>] [-hint <user hint>] [-home <full path to home>] [-admin] [-picture <full path to user image>]

Pass '-' instead of password in commands above to request prompt.
```

Then you'll want to do:

```
sudo createhomedir -c 2>&1 | grep -v "shell-init"
```

To add/remove users use dseditgroup:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a usernametoadd -t user admin
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a usernametoadd -t user wheel
```